# Google javascript map api works in VS 2017 but doesn't work when published to Azure

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 website that creates a map from an address using the google geocoding api and map javascript api. It works in Visual Studio 2017, but when I publish it to Azure, it doesn't work anymore. The map doesn't appear. The developer console shows no errors.

I use the Geocoding API to generate a latlong, from the street address. I added a debug statement to confirm that I am successfully talking to the api, and it does get lat long back.

The website is http://americanhorseproperties.com

```
<div id="map">


</div>

<a asp-page="./Index">Back to Gallery</a>

<input type="hidden" id="address" value="@Model.house.address 
@Model.house.city" />

<script>

// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

//gets address from the address hidden input element in body
var address = document.getElementById('address').value; 

//geocodes address and gets latlong 
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

if (status == 'OK') {
            console.log('location: Longitude: ', 
            results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            console.log('location: Latitude: ', 
            results[0].geometry.location.lat());

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 14, 
center: results[0].geometry.location });   
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: 
results[0].geometry.location }); //sets marker at new lat long

} else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + 
status);
        }

    });

}


</script>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
    key=KEY_REMOVED&callback=initMap">

</script>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Could you link to the problem page?

Comment: I don't get an error message but the map doesn't appear. I do get a lat long from the geocoding api though. If I watch the google cloud console it shows that the javascrip map api isn't even called from the published version of the website, however if I run it in VS 2017 google cloud console does show the map api being called. it registers a geocoding api call from both VS2017 and the published version. Edited the original post to clarify "doesn't work".                  The website is  americanhorseproperties.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to set "height" property for `<div id="map">`
[image]

Comment: That fixed it.  I'm curious why would it work in VS but fail when published.  Also, I had to put the style inline, it didn't do anything in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Problem.

The Google Maps API automatically adds the CSS properties "position: relative; overflow: hidden;" to the div that is used for displaying the map. When I manually remove any of these two properties in the developer console of the browser, the map becomes visible.

Make sure the div has a size that the map can fill.